# Automatically set PDF file type when saving edited PDFs in Preview

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, big-sur

Is there any way to automatically set the file type to PDF when saving a duplicated, edited PDF file in Preview?

My work flow is typically this:

1. Open a PDF file
2. Duplicate it for editing
3. Find and delete a large number of pages
4. Save the duplicate

But I always forget to select the file type as PDF when I am saving, and Preview defaults to PNG.  So I end up editing the file a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick test, following your steps, Preview seems to default to the last file format used.

You could try duplicating the file in the Finder (Command D) first, then opening that, editing, and saving.

Comment: You'd think that the default would be the current file that is being viewed. But who am I to say what is reasonable?